# how to do scrolling text automatically ,navigationview controller will do this?

Tags: iphone, scroll, uinavigationbar

i want to scroll text automatically when my view gets loaded and that should be bottom of my table view..
any suggestions appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an NSTimer to move the x-value of a UILabel, I suppose... Not very elegant though.